# Finding two variables at a time

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can we find out values of $a$ and $b$ in the equation $x^a - x^b = z$?

Where

1. $x$ and $z$ values are given.
2. $x,z,a,b$ are positive integers.
3. $a>b$.

For example in the given equation **$3^a - 3^b = 6480$**, find **$a$** and **$b$**. Is there any method to find the values of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Please check edits in your post.

Answer (score 1):

$3^a - 3^b = 6480 \implies 3^b(3^{a-b} - 1) = 3^4(3^4 - 1)$. This clearly shows $b=4$ and $a=8$.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thanks for the quick answer. On which basis you put value 4 i.e. 3^4

Comment: @Shiva I got it by factorizing $6480 = 3^4.2^4.5$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "long way." Excuse my lack of code writing knowledge to make it pretty.

x^a-x^b=z

Substitute Knowns: 3^a−3^b=6480

Take the log of both sides: log(3^a)-log(3^b)=log(6480)

Simplify Exponents: a*log(3)-b*log(3)=log(6480)

Isolate variables by dividing out log(3): a-b=[log(6480)]/[2*log(3)]

Solve logs: a-b=(3.811575)/(0.954242)

Divide: a-b=4

Find possible solutions for a-b which satisfy a>b and are positive intergers: 4-0, 5-1, 6-2, 7-3, 8-4, 9-5, 10-6, etc.

Identify possible solution which satisfies equation (Plug and play): a=8 b=4

Substitute for a and b: 3^8-3^4=6480

Solve Exponents: 6561-81=6480

Subtract: 6480=6480